# Supported Layout Managers in Eclipse Visual Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swing

I'm evaluating GUI builder tools for Swing. In the Eclipse Visual Editor 1.4 the list of the (natively) supported layout managers seems a bit short to me. Still no support for FormsLayout or TableLayout? The official documentation is a bit vague on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Eclipse Visual Editor I would suggest to look at [Instantiations Swing Designer](http://www.instantiations.com/windowbuilder/swingdesigner/index.html). IMO is the best UI designer for Eclipse platform. It supports most of the layouts available currently including FormLayout and MigLayout.

As far as layouts go there is nothing better then MigLayout - it can be used in place of any other. Swing Designer support for it is excellent.

NOTE: All that comes from experience. I'm not associated with Instatiations in any way :).

Comment: And where did the Instantiations Swing Designer go? A year later the link is broken...

Comment: It was taken over by Google and is totally free now :) Here is the link http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html